# What is this character that looks like 人? Is it some kind of quote?

Tags: kanji

I want to convert this text to kanji.  A translation is optional, I really want to just figure out what the kanji is electronically.

**人サベージ**？

I'm really not sure about the first character "hito" or the last character which looks like a 2 stroke something, but my dictionary has no such kanji.  Maybe these characters are some kind of enclosure similar to quotes?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a kanji. That's a vertical angle-bracket, i.e. `〈サベージ〉`. And yes, sometimes they can act as quotes, but as far as I know, there aren't any set-in-stone rules about their usage.

Comment: I think it's not ＜＞ but 〈〉. But yeah. +1 for brackets not kanji!

Comment: @Ash You may be right, but there aren't really rules, so I'd say they're basically identical other than visually

Comment: Technically `＜` is Unicode "FULLWIDTH LESS-THAN SIGN" and `〈` is "LEFT ANGLE BRACKET". But whatever the rules may be -- and I agree that people may sometimes use `＜` for a bracket -- it's clearly `〈` that is used here, by appearance. :)